# ExtJS: how to make a custom modal window with MessageBox buttons?

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250731/modal-extjs-window-not-masking-everything-behind-it-in-safari-and-chrome) [and this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053847/how-to-make-a-full-modal-window-in-ext-4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261013/extjs-message-box-with-custom-buttons), but none of them answer to my question.

I'd like to show a modal *custom* dialog box where there's a grid filled with the result of an AJAX call (it's a grid filled with JSON records actually) and a button "Ok" and a button "Cancel".

Do you know an easy way, or just a sample to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by 'easy way'? You basically extended for example `Ext.window.Window`, add toolbars, grid whatever else you need. Then create a controller and load your grid with the data. What seems to be a problem?

Comment: The standard buttons. Does the "Window" class handle this?

Comment: Yes. It has 'buttons' config property. Are you using ExtJs4?

Comment: Try to go through their MVC application creation guide. It's very helpful.

Comment: I've tried this one day, and the MVC model is so far from being finished that I've given up (for now) on the MVC model. See my thread (grumbling time!) here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?142886-MVC-documentation-are-you-overwhelmed

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. But it wasn't hard for me to get to ExtJs MVC at all. Honestly I never knew about ExtJs before Oct-Nov last year and now we have a project with 100+ files and classes and it works great.

Comment: When it's about JavaScript, I'm not the sharpest tool in the shelf. But when I read comments, I feel like I'm not the only one. It didn't took a long time to use ExtJS (3 days to do this http://olivierpons.fr/2012/01/10/extjs-exemple-dun-developpement/ .

Comment: But mastering ExtJS **MVC** is not simple. Here I explain the basis, which is very simple : http://olivierpons.fr/2011/08/12/extjs-4-et-le-mvc-modele-vue-controleur-howto/ (and french people asked me a lot about that), but once again, this makes things much more complicated to me than the traditional `classes` derivation approach.

Comment: Err well you say "before Oct-Nov last year"! So something like 6 months! I've worked something like 20 days in a row with ExtJS, and 5 days in a row with the MVC model, this may explain why it seems so hard for me to master all this. Maybe in 3 months I'll feel more comfortable ;)